# GroupBy a list of tuple c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a set of results that I need to transform into a different format. The results is from `Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>>` resources. The key is the language culture LCID and the tuple are the neutral texts and the localized texts.

By example, the result given is:

```
1.  3084, [0]: Female : Femme, [1] Man : Homme, [2] Other : Autre
2.  1033, [0]: Female : Women, [1] Man : Man, [2] Other : Other
```

So by now I need to transform those data by group by on neutral text. The final set of values need to fit in this class:

```
public class StructuredLocalized
{
     public string NeutralText { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, string> LocalizedTexts { get; set; } 
}
```

The final result should be like that:

```
1.  Female, [0]: 3084 : Femme, [1]: 1033: Women
2.  Man, [0]: 3084 : Homme, [1] : 1033 : Man
3.  Other, [0]: 3084 : Autre, [1]: 1033 : Autre
```

I unable to write the group by clause to achieve that formatting. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var tmp = (from r in x select (from v in r.Value select new { r.Key, v.Item1, v.Item2}))
  .SelectMany(a=>a).ToLookup(a=>a.Item1 , a => new { a.Key, a.Item2});

var results = (from r in tmp select new 
     StructuredLocalized{ 
       NeutralText = r.Key , 
       LocalizedTexts = r.ToDictionary(a=>a.Key, a=>a.Item2) 
 } ) ;





int line = 1;
 foreach(var r in results)
 {
    Console.Write ("{0}. {1}," , line++, r.NeutralText);

    int j = 0;
    foreach(var k in r.LocalizedTexts)
    {
        Console.Write(" [{0}]: {1} {2}, " , j++,  k.Key, k.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.  The trick is to flatten the dictionary out into anonymous objects that contain the 3 values before grouping.  But I would suggest creating types specific to your domain instead if you can.

```
var idToNames = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, string>>>
{
    {
        "3084",
        new List<Tuple<string, string>>
            {
                Tuple.Create("Female", "Femme"),
                Tuple.Create("Male", "Homme"),
                Tuple.Create("Other", "Autre"),
            }
    },
    {
        "1033",
        new List<Tuple<string, string>>
            {
                Tuple.Create("Female", "Woman"),
                Tuple.Create("Male", "Man"),
                Tuple.Create("Other", "Other"),
            }
    }
};

var nameToSpecific = 
    idToNames.SelectMany(
        kvp => kvp.Value.Select(
            t => new 
            { 
                LCID = kvp.Key, 
                GenericName = t.Item1, 
                SpecificName = t.Item2 
            }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.GenericName)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key, 
        g => g.Select(
            x => Tuple.Create(x.LCID, x.SpecificName)).ToList());

foreach (var kvp in nameToSpecific)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    foreach(var tup in kvp.Value)
        Console.WriteLine("    " + tup);
}
```

Results

```
Female
    (3084, Femme)
    (1033, Woman)
Male
    (3084, Homme)
    (1033, Man)
Other
    (3084, Autre)
    (1033, Other)
```